# How to center nav in div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center the navigation bar in the middle of the div body. I want the navigation bar to go from one side of the div to the other but have the list in the ul to be center in the middle of the div if that makes sense. I can't seem to figure it out even after trying online examples. Thanks

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: #505050 ;
}

#body {
    width: 75%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: center;
    background-color: #C0C0C0;
    height: 100%;
}

.nav {

}
.nav ul {
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;

}

.nav li {
    list-style: none;
    font-family: Arial Black;
    padding: 0px;
    height:40px;
    width: 120px;
    line-height: 40px;
    border: none;
    float: left;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    display:inline;

}

.nav a {
    display: block;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 60px;

}
```

```html
<div id="body">
    <h2>Hello World!</h2>
    <div class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home<a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About<a></li>
            <li><a href="#">News<a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact<a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i attach fix here http://jsfiddle.net/o4716uo9/

use `inline-block` for `li`

Answer (score 0):

`background` property should be setted in ul element, not li, in your case. Delete the `float` in nav li. Also, the a element it isn't closed correctly. Main changes:

```
.nav ul {
  background-color: #cccccc;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 120px;
  [...]
}
```

I'll recommend you to take a look at the [bootstrap framework](http://getbootstrap.com/). It could be interesting for you.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things you can change to correct the issue:

**1)** Your `<a>` elements have a width of `60px`. You can remove this.

**2)** You `.nav li` has a width of `120px`. I would change this to `25%` (If there are only going to be four navigational items).

http://jsfiddle.net/xLnz90ek/

Is that any closer to the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you’re trying to do?

```css
* { margin:0; padding:0 }


html {
  background-color: #505050;
  font-size: 4vw;
}

header {
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
}

nav {
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0.2rem 0;
}

nav a {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  font-family: Arial Black;
  font-size: 1rem;
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 0.3rem;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h2>Hello World!</h2>
  <nav>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">News</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </nav>
</header>
```